# Add new section in frontpage in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Can someone help me. I purchased Avada theme, and in home page, I want to add my own html elements to make new section. But I can't find .php file in FTP.

I tried to find some .php file for homepage but without success.

Comment: add from admin panel, which home page you select add edit that home page from pages

Comment: @Imran Saleem
yes, but I need to do that using FTP and find exactly .php file aqnd copy in child theme folder and write my own code.

I can't solve using admin dashboard panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per word press structure you can not file .php file. everything stored in database.

If you wan to add code in page then follow the following way, And there are also many more way to add html or php content in page.

1. Using shotcode
2. Using template file
3. Following given bellow steps

**Steps:**

1. Login into your admin dashborad "domainname/wp-admin"
2. Enter username and password
3. http://screencast.com/t/T4bWQDAIEw1C
4. http://screencast.com/t/YCalLxzOM8Lp
5. http://screencast.com/t/JM97LjDDdO